# Send dynamic textinput across activities

Tags: java, android

For the first time, I want to create a menu with multiples `EditText`. I've shown 4 `EditText` in my menu and I've created a `button` to add another `EditText`.

I want to know how to get the texts contained in the editTexts to send them to another activity.

My code is :

```
private void addTableRow() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
    Integer nbjoueur = parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1;
    String nbjoueurString = Integer.toString(nbjoueur);
    EditText playername = (EditText)rowView.findViewById(R.id.joueurnew);
    playername.setId(R.id.player + nbjoueur);
    playername.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.placeholder_nomjoueur) + " " + nbjoueur);
    playername.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    playername.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
}
 public void launch_game(){

        EditText player1 = findViewById(R.id.joueur1);
        EditText player2 = findViewById(R.id.joueur2);
        EditText player3 = findViewById(R.id.joueur3);
        EditText player4 = findViewById(R.id.joueur4);
        Intent intent = new Intent ( MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class );
        intent.putExtra ( "player1", player1.getText().toString() );
        intent.putExtra ( "player2", player2.getText().toString() );
        intent.putExtra ( "player3", player3.getText().toString() );
        intent.putExtra ( "player4", player4.getText().toString() );

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This is only sending my `4 statics EditText`, not the `EditText` content created dynamically. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I can't see any "dynamic" edittext from your code

Comment: I'ts when I create a `addTableRow`, I call a xml layout with only 1 `EditText`.